# Problem to manage branches with gitlab on a specific project

Tags: git, gitlab

Hello there so i have a problem with git/gitlab

I work in a project where we have those branches on gitlab (master, sprint_XX, recette and develop). From there for each ticket that the client make we create a new branch from develop. Up until there nothing weird.

HEres where it gets crazy. When a ticket is done we don't pull from develop with rebase before we commit and push into develop. And the reason why is because the client can at any moment say that he doesn't want a specific ticket in the sprint. even if it's in develop or recette or sprint_XX.

Knowing that if we do pull from develop before commit & push we basically can't go back  and we destroyed our branch and if the client want to remove a ticket well we have to redo all the work.

We called an architect to solves this problem. But we still have big issues such as conflict that we soleves directly on a merge request , and still have to redo our work cause sometipes when two tickets are on the sames files we basically gonna have conflict and its a pain. Specially when you have 25 commits to redo.

My question is (and on purpose i don't want to tell you guys what the architect gave us as solution to "solve" our problem because i want you guys to give me something fresh.) What is the best way to work this out without major problem.

I sincerely & deeply thank you guys in advance, for all the help you might give me.

Comment: Have you taken a look to train https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/merge_trains.html ?

Comment: Why do you say you have to "redo" all the work? `git rebase` (even `git cherry-pick`) can be used to pull off an amazing number of tricks hat sounds like you should be able to use to ease your workflows without having to go through hell every single time. Perhaps an example with ascii charts would help us visualize why it gets so difficult.

Comment: And, just as a pun, the fact that someone is a software architect does not mean that they know a lot about how to pull off stuff with git.... I am sure plenty of the guys that lurk around for git questions like me have plenty of horror stories about "architects" trying to _fix_ git problems. :-D

Comment: Atomic commits at least facilitate the process, if some put off feature is going to be included later, you have to resolve conflicts, preserving that feature behavior. Only manual merge i guess.

Comment: Hard to say without knowing more but sounds more like an organisational issue rather than a technical one.